# how to add increasingly more to an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there a way to have Q different updates of the following kind:

```
v[start] = v[start] + 1;
v[start + 1] = v[start + 1] + 2;
v[start + 2] = v[start + 2] + 3
```

and so on.. to the position end

```
v[end] = v[end] + end - start + 1
```

in O(N+Q)? 
I mean something like difference arrays. Can you please help me?
If it helps, the array is initially only 0s.
Clarification:
N = array size
Q = Number of updates
All the updates have different starting and ending indices and I do not need to access any element of the array in between the updates. I only need them after i performed each update.

Comment: I haven't thought of anything fancy, but I think that a `for` loop would do the job.

Comment: Yeah. I was looking for an O(Q+N) solution. And a for loop would be O(N*Q)

Comment: Q is the number of updates.

Comment: If the initial array has all 0s, then `std::iota(v + start, v + end, v[start])` should do the trick.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can just keep track of the start and end of each index range and produce the elements afterwards, but I can't quite work out the details... I would write out a few such sums by hand and look for patterns.

Comment: So you start with an array `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...` and you want to have an array `Q, 2*Q, 3*Q, ...` in the end?

Comment: Note that O(N) is about _asymptotic_ complexity of _some_ basic operation, and thus O(N+Q) does not make sense here, as either N or Q can always be described in terms of eachother, meaning the actual asymptotic complexity is O(N). Are you mixing up the term with actual _instruction count_? Also, does an increased constant magnitude of runtime actually affect you in practice? I see this misunderstanding of asymptotic bounds all the time, leading to much Q&A confusion here on the site.

Comment: I believe you left out the detail that the start and end points can be different for each update. (At least I assume they can, since otherwise this is trivial.)

Comment: I did forget to include that. The starting and ending indices are different for each update

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I read the problem as

```
v[start] = v[start] + 1;
v[start + 1] = v[start] + 2;
v[start + 2] = v[start + 1] + 3
```

---

This sounds like the job for *scan* methods (compare e.g. with Haskell's `scanl`), e.g. [`std::transform_exclusive_scan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_exclusive_scan):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector v{0, 0, 0, 0};
  int value_increment = 1;
  std::transform_inclusive_scan(
      v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
      std::plus<int>{},
      [&value_increment](int x) { return x + value_increment++; });
  // 1 3 6 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing every member in a range in a similar way, so [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) does what you want. The only mildly tricky thing is an extra variable that is increased every time. (Example not compiled or tested)

```
int i = 0;
std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::begin(v),
               [&](int e) { return e + (++i); });
```